# How to remove a data from a list

Tags: apex, list, csv

I got this CSV Data Debug:

```
15:40:47.129 (129957383)|USER_DEBUG|[77]|DEBUG|CSV:(Ticket__c:{First_Name__c=Mar, Last_Name__c=Roxas, Email_Address__c=maro@gmail.com
, Status__c=Attended, Type__c=Non-Ticketed}, Ticket__c:{First_Name__c=Grace, Last_Name__c=Poe, Email_Address__c=gripo@yahoomail.com
, Status__c=Attended, Type__c=Non-Ticketed}, Ticket__c:{First_Name__c=Jejomar, Last_Name__c=Binay, Email_Address__c=jomay@hotmail.com
, Status__c=Attended, Type__c=Non-Ticketed}, Ticket__c:{First_Name__c=Rodrigo, Last_Name__c=Duterte, Email_Address__c=thirtythree@alphasys.com
, Status__c=Attended, Type__c=Non-Ticketed}, Ticket__c:{First_Name__c=Melai, Last_Name__c=Hontiveros, Email_Address__c=melai@gmail.com
, Status__c=Attended, Type__c=Non-Ticketed}, Ticket__c:{First_Name__c=John, Last_Name__c=Lazy, Email_Address__c=john.lazy@gmail.com
, Status__c=Attended, Type__c=Non-Ticketed}, Ticket__c:{First_Name__c=Vicmar, Last_Name__c=Dahalili, Email_Address__c=vicdahalili@hotmail.com
, Status__c=Attended, Type__c=Non-Ticketed})
```

I got this Update data:

```
15:40:47.130 (130466282)|USER_DEBUG|[88]|DEBUG|Update Ticket: (Ticket__c:{Id=a0d9000000Bz3QCAAZ, First_Name__c=Melai, Last_Name__c=Hontiveros, Email_Address__c=melai@gmail.com, Status__c=Attended, Type__c=Issued}, Ticket__c:{Id=a0d9000000Byu6EAAR, First_Name__c=John, Last_Name__c=Lazy, Email_Address__c=john.lazy@gmail.com, Status__c=Attended, Type__c=Issued})
```

How can I remove the Update data from CSV Data?..
I tried this code:

```
for(Ticket__c csvtickets: ticketlist){                  
    for(Ticket__c utickets: ticket_sa){                                                                             
        if(!csvtickets.First_Name__c.contains(utickets.First_Name__c) && !csvtickets.Last_Name__c.contains(utickets.Last_Name__c) && !csvtickets.Email_Address__c.contains(utickets.Email_Address__c)){

            csvtickets.Status__c = 'Attended';
            csvtickets.Type__c = 'Non-Ticketed';
            ticket_new.add(csvtickets);

        }                                           
    }
}
```

But what it output is this:

```
Mar Roxas   maro@gmail.com
Mar Roxas   maro@gmail.com
Grace   Poe gripo@yahoomail.com
Grace   Poe gripo@yahoomail.com
Jejomar Binay   jomay@hotmail.com
Jejomar Binay   jomay@hotmail.com
Rodrigo Duterte thirtythree@alphasys.com
Rodrigo Duterte thirtythree@alphasys.com
Melai   Hontiveros  melai@gmail.com
John    Lazy    john.lazy@gmail.com
Vicmar  Dahalili    vicdahalili@hotmail.com
Vicmar  Dahalili    vicdahalili@hotmail.com
```

`ticket_list` is the CSV Data and `ticket_sa` is the Update data

Answer (score 0):

Obviously the answer resides in the algorithm.

The problem yours has is the following

(Let's pretend we have a list with {A,B,C,D} and a update list {B,C})

Through the first iteration, the first for is processing A. The inside for is processing A as well.

It goes :

first loop

is (A != B) --> yes, add it to the new list (Intended)

is (A != C) --> yes, add it to the new list (Not intended as we already have A !)

second loop

is (B != B) --> no, don't add it to the new list (Intended)

is (B != C) --> yes, add it to the new list (Not intendend as we don't want to add B to the new list !)

You got the point at this point.

So you have to put a third for loop (inside the if (csvElementt != upElement)), processing the new list created to see if the element isn't already in the list. 
This way you won't have A) duplicate B) elements not intended

Here is the code with your variables' names

```
List<..> newTicketsList = new List<..>();
for(Ticket__c csvTicket: ticketList){

  for(Ticket__c uTicket: ticket_sa){

    if(!csvTicket.First_Name__c.contains(uTicket.First_Name__c) && !csvTicket.Last_Name__c.contains(uTicket.Last_Name__c) && !csvTicket.Email_Address__c.contains(uTicket.Email_Address__c)){

        for (Ticket__c nTicket : newTicketsList) {

            if (!nTicket.First_Name__c.contains(uTicket.First_Name__c) && !nTicket.Last_Name__c.contains(uTicket.Last_Name__c) && !nTicket.Email_Address__c.contains(uTicket.Email_Address__c)) {

               csvTicket.Status__c = 'Attended';
               csvTicket.Type__c = 'Non-Ticketed';
               newTicketsList .add(csvTicket);
            }
        }
    }                                           
  }
}
```

Comment: Its not working sir.. Where did you get the newTicketsList? It can't go on the for loop of newTicketsList. Since at first place it was empty.

Comment: newTicketsList is = to your ticket_new if I understood your code well. This is the list you want to populate. You can rename it. It's just a naming convention makin the code more readable for you and others that might read your code


And a forEach with a empty list (which was created before the first for), you can check that [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24845281/how-does-a-for-each-loop-guard-against-an-empty-list](here).  If the list is empty, the for won't execute, nor it won't raise an error so it's fine.